# Why the python __builtins__ length changed in debug mode vs terminal running?

Tags: python, debugging, built-in

I found the same python script, when I debugged it within vscode, I found there are only 45

> len(dir(__builtins__))

> 45

But in terminal mode to run my python script: python3 myscripty.py, then I got:

> len(dir(__builtins__))

> 156

What caused the debug mode there are less __builtins__ ?
Both my debug and terminal use the same python version 3.10.2
Is that my vscode python debug settings lost something?

Comment: what do you see when you use `print` instead of `len`? That will give you a hint.

Comment: thanks for your note. when I added more debug message, found in debug mode, the \_\_builtins__ is a dict, but in terminal to run my script, the \_\_builtins__ is a module class. That's the reason why the len() has different result.